# Displaying IP address path geographically

Tags: networking, macos

Is there any software or website for showing IP address path?

this image is snapshot from a software by a person:

[image]

this shows the local IP address to the destination IP address's path.

But I don't know what's the software's name, who can tell me what's it?

---

**EDIT-01**

I use Mac OS.

Comment: Please note that this site is about software recommendation, which means that we recommend applications, and websites are off-topic here. Glad that I could hep you with the answer, though :-)

Comment: After you accepted my answer, I have only just noticed that you editted to add "`I use Mac OS.`". This, and a budget, are the two things which questioners most often froget to add. Since Mac has a smaller market share, people will tend to post answers for WIndows, if you don't state an o/s. I added the [tag:macos] for you. I don't know if you were willing to pay. If so, please state a budget; otherwise, please use the [tag:gratis] tag. It's all in [ask]. Please note that I am not criticising you, but trying to help you get better answers in future

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The magic word is [traceroute](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Traceroute), so you are looking for a `visual traceroute`.

Since you don’t tell us which operating system you use, or whether you want to pay for it or not (please read [ask] and tell us this sort of thing in future; the more information you give us, the more we can help you), I guess at the most common answers : Windows and [gratis](/questions/tagged/gratis).

I found [this program](https://sourceforge.net/projects/openvisualtrace/) which gives this sort of display

[image]

If that is not what you want, please update your question.